# Draw to YCbCr color to screen

Tags: colors, drawing, color-space

I'm attempting to draw to screen with a bunch of colors that I have in YCbCr coordinates. However, all drawing libraries that I can find (Windows or cross-platform) want to specify colors in RGB and I don't want to convert and lose precision. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the monitor is RGB you will have to convert the colors somewhere. If you do it yourself, or let some third party library do it for you doesn't really matter. I believe SDL lets you put YCbCr/YUV-values directly. But the colors will be converted to RGB either by software or by your graphics card on the way to the monitor.

Comment: Well, here's the thing: yes, all displays have R,G,B subpixels, but there are many HDTVs that prefer a YCbCr input. Additionally, you can set your video card to output YCbCr, so I am trying to avoid YCbCr -> RGB (rounded to nearest integer) -> YCbCr. I will check out SDL, but I'm really looking for a solution that passes the input to the graphics card without converting it back to RGB.

Comment: Ok, so you want to output YCbCr to the screen directly with your video card. I have never tried that, although I do it regularly with special hardware (BlackMagic Decklink cards). On those you usually get direct access to the frame buffer (4:2:2 uyvy 8 or 10 bit on Decklink cards). I believe it will be hard to find a way to directly do this on a regular graphics card, I would guess it always does a conversion from the regular RGB frame buffer before sending out the signal.

Perhaps the overlay video modes work differently. I would say that it's your best bet.